# How to convert bounding box coordinates obtained by darkflow into real world coordinates?

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, yolo, darkflow

i use realsense D435, and python 3.7, tensorflow 1.14, darkflow yolo v.2.

1. Are the camera coordinates different from the current coordinates?
2. How should the camera coordinates and the current coordinates match?
3. I want to know the center value of an object with the coordinates of the bounding box of darkflow.

I don't know much about vision. please help

Please let me know if there is a better way.

Comment: 1)NO 2) using calibration  3) after doing calibration you'll get a matrix to transform the object center from pixel to world coordinates.

Comment: After using camera calibration, should I take an arbitrary point at the object's center position and convert that pixel to world coordinate?

Comment: You'll be able to transform any point you want from pixel to world. this is what you' are looking for https://www.fdxlabs.com/calculate-x-y-z-real-world-coordinates-from-a-single-camera-using-opencv/